# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When trying to insert the following information into my database I get "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code error?" error.

My code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class SecurePages_AddBackup
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Dim customer As Integer
    Dim backupDate As String
    Dim Server As Integer
    Dim Status As String
    Dim Product As Integer
    Dim Details As String

    customer = ddlCustomer.SelectedValue
    backupDate = clDate.SelectedDate
    Server = DDLserver.SelectedValue
    Status = DDLStatus.Text
    Product = DDLproduct.SelectedValue
    Details = txtDetails.Text




    Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO Backup(CustomerID, Date, ServerID, Status, ProductID, Details) Values (@Customer, @BackupDate, @Server, @Status, @Product, @Details)"

    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Backups.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer", customer)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BackupDate", backupDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", Server)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", Product)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", Details)
    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()




    conn.Close()

    lblStatus.Text = "Backup added to the database!"
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are you using an .MDF file in your project or SQL Express, or SQL Server?  If you are using either express or sql server... here is a connection string format that may help you.    

Data Source=YOUR-SERVER-NAME\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=YOUR-DB-NAME;" Integrated Security=True providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: I'm using an MDF file in my project. It breaks at the line of code with   `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() `

Comment: When the program crashes I get the following error in the browser Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Backup'. But still not sure where the error code be near the keyword 'Backup'?

Comment: Inspect the exception and its InnerException, it will contain the actual exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Backup` is a [reserved keyword](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL Server.

Try `INSERT INTO [Backup]`